# I'm doing an image preview with jQuery. But I cannot post the data I clicked after preview. How Can I Make It Real?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, jquery-plugins, backend

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 //Define an array
 var fileCollection = new Array();

 $('#file').on('change', function (e) {
     var files = e.target.files;
     $.each(files, function (i, file) {

         fileCollection.push(file);//I'm adding the previewed pictures into the series.

         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         reader.onload = function (e) {
             var template = '<li>' +
                 '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" width="50" height="50"> ' +
                 '<label>' + file.name + file.size + '</label> <input type="text" name="title">' +
                 ' <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info upload">Yükle</button>' +
                 ' <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove">Sil</a>' +
                 '</li>';
             $("#prewiew").append(template);
             $("#file").val('');
         }
     });
 });
```

How can I get the data of the image I added with the name of the upload class and post it ?
I want the user to submit the data to the database by clicking the upload button after previewing.
I want to submit without using a form tag, is this possible ? Because using a form tag I will post a lot of data with an image.
That's why I want to dynamically send only the pictures in the preview section ?

```
$(document).on("click", ".upload", function () {
/* I want to submit without using a form tag, is this possible? Because using a form tag I will post a lot of data with an image.
 * That's why I want to dynamically send only the pictures in the preview section.   */

    //If the user clicks the upload button, I want to send the values in the array. But I'm having trouble. Do you have any ideas?

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/ImagePost/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: fileCollection, //I cannot send the defined array and its values.
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function () {
        },
    });
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove", function () {
    var removeDelete = $(this).closest("li");
    removeDelete.remove();
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Not sure what the `values` may be in your example, but there appears to be a syntax error with the trailing comma after the success function reference. Check the browser console tab to ensure no errors. Also, there is a network tab there as well, where you can see the XHR requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can Use the following code to send only the picture

```
 var pictureData = new FormData(document.getElementById("yourFileID"));
 pictureData.append("label", "myPicture"); //this is to identify on server
 $.ajax({
     url: "/Home/ImagePost/",
     type: "POST",
     data: pictureData,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function () {
     }
 })
```